# Kafka Spring Deserialzer returnType static method never called

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Here is the error I get:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing 
key/value for partition distance-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past 
the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No type information in headers 
and no default type provided
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.
```

springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:370)

And applicaiton-dev.yml:

```
spring:
  json:
    use:
      type:
        headers: false
    value:
      default:
        type: Object
        method: com.mycompany.mypackage.KafkaConfig.returnType
```

Also tried with:

```
consumer:
  bootstrap-servers: 10.10.5.189:9092
  value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
  enable-auto-commit: false
  auto-offset-reset: earliest
  properties:
    spring:
      json:
        trusted:
          packages: '*'
        value:
          default:
            method: com.mycompany.mypackage.KafkaConfig.returnTypee
```

There were no warning but i put printlin in static method and it never fired? What gives?

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "distance", groupId = "${kafka.myinfo.id}")
 public void handle(CustDeletedEvent custDeletedEvent) {
        log.debug("received jsonNode: "+ userDeletedEvent);
```

KafkaConfig.java

```
  // NEVER CALLED!!!
  public static JavaType returnType(byte[] data, Headers headers) {
    System.out.println("return type called data.length="+data.length);
    JavaType custDeletedEvent = 
  TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(CustDeletedEvent.class);
   return custDeletedEvent;
 }
```

Latest config:

```
  kafka:
bootstrap-servers: 10.10.5.189:9092
producer:
  bootstrap-servers: 10.10.5.189:9092
  value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
consumer:
  bootstrap-servers: 10.10.5.189:9092
  value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
  enable-auto-commit: false
  auto-offset-reset: earliest
  properties:
    spring:
      json:
        trusted:
          packages: '*'
        value:
          method: mypackage.config.KafkaConfig.returnType
```

Spring Kafka configured here

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

here is exact yaml:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: 10.10.5.189:9092
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: 10.10.5.189:9092
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: 10.10.5.189:9092
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      enable-auto-commit: false
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            trusted:
              packages: '*'
            value:
              method: com.service.cust.impl.returnType
```

Comment: Why are you configuring below `spring.json`? That should start with `spring.kafka` to add de-/serializer classes to topics.

Comment: still getting error after fixing as above

Comment: @daniu have you not seen my update?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to go in `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json...`.

Comment: I am still seeing the error error see update to question above

Comment: Your YAML indentation is wrong, it's `...value.method` not `...value.default.method`.

Comment: Can you indicate all properties that need to be set for this to work. I have posted my whole json consumer config

Comment: Oh ok I see let me try again

Comment: Nope, still seeing same error message and it never files. I update again above

Comment: It never fires at all. Is there some other settings I also need to configure?

Comment: Your YAML still looks badly formed to me. At this point, I need you to post you project someplace (hopefully stripped down to the bare minimum) so I can see what you have done wrong. Dealing with it going back and forth like this seems fruitless.

Comment: I am also seeing warning The configuration 'spring.json.value.method' was supplied but isn't a known config.

Comment: there is not where else that spring.json.value.method is configured except under consumer

Comment: Maybe I need to specify a specific version of Spring boot. Can you post a configuration set that works for this. My project has many files so its not easy to strip down.

Comment: Where can I programatically set the method?  I saw it in the documentation but I dont know where in the code to do this initialization?

Comment: This functionality was added in version 2.5; there is a test case [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/c43a85f67f2a6209d8473c8df76252029c5b6a55/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/support/serializer/JsonSerializationTests.java#L316-L325) that configures the method programmatically; when doing that, you have to provide the deserializer object to the consumer factory in a constructor rather than via consumer properties.

Comment: I need to know for what version of Spring Boot and Spring Kafka this works.

Comment: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogAccessor
2020-08-06 09:19:40.759 ERROR 32599 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

Comment: I used Spring 2.3.2.RELEASE but then get log accessor error. Also for the programatic setting I need to see where you run this exactly. I just see these snippets but I need to see where this is placed in the config?

Comment: You should always let Boot manage the versions. Boot 2.3 requires Spring Kafka 2.5 and  Spring Framework 5.2. Just specifiy the Boot version and everything else will be managed to the correct versions by Boot. It seems you are using an older version of Spring Framework with Boot 2.3. Boot compatibilities are pulled in here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle

Comment: What version of boot do I need to use?

Comment: So you are saying 2.3 boot is fine but I need to not specify the Spring Framework ... ok let me check

Comment: The feature was added in spring-kafka 2.5; use Boot 2.3.2 and don't specify a version for any other Spring projects; Boot will automatically pull in the right versions. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-dependency-management

Comment: I tried that but I am using JHipster project. I will try again. If I nee d to specify it what version exactly of 5.2.0.RELEASE ?

Comment: When I remove the version I get this error: 'build.plugins.plugin[org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin].dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-core:jar is missing. @ line 682, column 37

Comment: I am not familiar with JHipster - you should take it up with them - the current spring framework version is 5.2.8 https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework#learn I already gave you a link to Boot's dependencies.

Comment: Ok, for setting programatically I know what to do on the Deserializer code I have seen in documentation but I need to know where this is to be run?

Comment: I have another question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63275816/how-to-i-programaticaly-set-jsondeserializer-typevalue-method-in-spring-kafka  I know basically but not exactly where to run the code that does this. And if I need to reference this anywhere in the listener etc. Because I am not sure if I can do the JHipster upgrade to 2.3 Spring. Its still stuck on 2.1.8