# KafkaListener not resolving containerFactory with "#{__listener.getContainerFactory()}"

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using the following methods to get the KafkaListener properties.
But it does not resolve the containerFactory value. But it works for topics and groupId.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{__listener.getTopics()}",
            groupId = "#{__listener.getGroupId()}",
            containerFactory =  "#{__listener.getContainerFactory()}")
    public void sampleTestTopicListener(@Payload byte[] data,

.....
 @Value("sampleTestListenerContainerFactory")
    private String containerFactory ;

    public String  getContainerFactory(){
        return containerFactory;
    }
....
Spring-kafka-2.2.5.RELEASE 

I get the following error :
A component required a bean named '#{__listener.getContainerFactory()}' that could not be found.

Changing the containerFactory value to "sampleTestListenerContainerFactory" instead of spEL, it works fine.
```

How can I set it using the current beans property?

Answer (score 1):

The `containerFactory` option on that `@KafkaListener` annotation cannot be as a SpEL expression. You can use a property placeholder resolution though. Like this:

```
containerFactory = "${sampleTestListenerContainerFactory}"
```

but it is better to use a real bean name anyway: the `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` really must be a bean...

Another note: the version of Spring for Apache Kafka 2.2.5 is out of support. It has reached its End of Life long time ago. It is more practical to stay with the latest versions: https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#learn

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
My requirement was to provide a base Listener handler and in a derived class the clients of the base class can provide these properties so that every client does not need to write the full handler signature 
```
@KafkaListener(..attributes given in derived class)
  public void sampleTopicListener(
      @Payload byte[] data,
      @Header...{
loginfo(..)
processmessage(data) - derived class will override this function)
commit
```
What was the reason for not supporting spEL for containerfactory?
Is there any other alternative ?

Comment: Is it really necessary for this `containerFactory` option? See its JavaDocs `If not specified, the default container factory is used, if any.`. so, you can just omit this option and implementors of your class must just provide a `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean instead.

Comment: This will limit the containerFactory to one consumer config only. Multiple  derived classes  can not specify a separate default bean for the containerfactory as there is only one bean of type kafkaListenerContainerFactory in the same application?

concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setConsumerFactory(the config needed for the client)

Comment: OK. Agree with you: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1661. It is not possible at the moment, but we will look for the requested support.

Comment: While we should support expressions here, it is generally preferable to use a single container factory (especially with Spring Boot) and add a `ContainerCustomizer` to it, to adjust properties for each container created by the factory. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63108344/spring-kafka-requirements-for-supporting-multiple-consumers/63117327#63117327) for an example.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the support.